# How large was Henry the Fowler's army?

Tags: middle-ages, warfare, saxons

About how many fighting men was [Henry the Fowler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_the_Fowler#Wars_over_Lotharingia), King of East Frankia (919 - 936) and Duke of Saxony (912 - 936) able to field during a given campaign?

Comment: What have you found out so far? Telling people where you have looked and what you've found helps those trying to answer your question. Also, I'm not sure if this isn't a little broad.